# MariaDb Query error

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm new on MariaDb, and i have a error with a query.

```
SELECT C.NUMASE,
      (SELECT SUM(B.TIPUS) AS TOT 
       FROM ( 
              SELECT A.NUMASE, CASE WHEN A.TIVA IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS TIPUS 
              FROM CONTA_001_CAS00118 as A 
              WHERE C.NUMASE = A.NUMASE and IFNULL(A.SR_DELETED,' ') <> 'T'
            ) AS B
       ) AS SUMT
FROM ( 
       SELECT DISTINCT NUMASE  
       FROM CONTA_001_CAS00118 
       WHERE IVA IS NOT NULL and IFNULL(SR_DELETED,' ') <> 'T' 
      ) AS C
```

The error is :

> Error de SQL(1054): Unknown column C.NUMASE in 'where clausule

Can anyone help me?

Thank you
Peter.

Comment: There is a comma (,) missing in the last edit and for me the query does not generate any errors

Comment: I'm sorry, i have error to copy query.

Comment: The comma disappeared when @Nayantara edited it but that is not so relevant. When I added back the comma I can run the query without an issue.

Comment: But isn't the reference to `C.NUMASE` too deep to see it?